# MySQL - update row if some column value equals else insert row (NO DUPLICATE KEY)

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, insert-update

I have a table that stores meta values, however, in insert/update I want to perform - there is no unique key **(not even a combination of columns)**.

1 column stores ID of a post, 1 a varchar key of a meta value and 1 holds the meta value...

Now the thing is, the table **CAN** contain duplicate rows, easily, this can happen:

```
id_post   |   key   |   value
   5        'bobber'     4
   3        'locer'      2
   5        'bobber'     4
```

Now what I want to do is to do a *variation* of insert or duplicate key update, problem is, I don't have the key that would trigger the update.

If the `key` value is already existing in the table, I want to update the corresponding `value` column(s). If it is not, I want to insert a brand new row.

All I found ends up with adding a key constraint, which is something I *can't* do.
Also, I do **not** want to create a stored procedure/function.

Any help please? Thank you :-)

Comment: You can't do this in SQL, you need a programming language that can first do a `SELECT`, then either `UPDATE` or `INSERT` depending on whether it found anything.

Comment: Your desire doesn't make sense.  If you want to `update` when a key exists, then you are saying -- in a round-about-way -- that you want the key to be unique, at least for new data going into the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It does in a wider viewpoint, the problem is I do not want to update if KEY exists, but if a COLUMN VALUE exists. Anyway, fact that I don't use duplicate-ish values does not mean someone/something else isn't using them... Some systems are designed in a way they do not store e.g. array as 1 serialized value, but the ~array values are transcripted to DB as rows. I hope you get it know :)